# Whats wrong with this batch script?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:a
title DISCORD.PY BOT RUNNER
cls
color 0a
python bot.py

if errorlevel == 1 (
    color 4
    echo.
    echo ERROR
    echo.
    echo [1] CLOSE : [2] RESTART

    set /p error = ""

    if %error% == 1 exit
    if %error% == 2 goto a
)

echo BOT IS CLOSED
echo.
echo [1] CLOSE

set /p closed = ""

if %closed% == 1 exit
```

Can anyone say me whats wrong with this script?
I see there are nothing wrong.
Bc i want to make an discord.py bot starter.

Comment: The errorlevel you're currently working with is that between `python.exe` and `cmd.exe`, but I'd assume that you want the exit/error code between `bot.py` and `python.exe` instead. If that assumption is correct, then the content of `bot.py` may be what requires modification, and you haven't posted any of that. As for what is wrong with your batch script, not only should `if errorlevel == 1 (` be changed to `if not errorlevel 0 (`, and if you're not going to use `choice.exe`, you'll need delayed expansion with `set /p`, as you are both defining and using a variable within a parenthesized block.

Answer (score 0):

`errorlevel == 1` - the string `errorlevel` will never be the same as the string `1`. You need the *value* of `errorlevel`, that is `%errorlevel%`.

Since you are setting the value of `error` *within* a parenthesised sequence of statements (ie. a `block`) then batch will evaluate the *entire* statement from the `if` to the closing parenthesis, and substitute for each `%variable%` with the valu of that variable **at the time the statement was parsed**, that is, **before** it is executed. You are changing the value of `error` within the block, so you need to extract its **run-time** value for testing and thus you need to invoke `delayedexpansion`. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947

ALSO : `set /p variable =` will establish a variable named  variable<kbd>Space</kbd> not variable. The space before the `=` **is** significant.